# Please help me to understand 納得させて and ごまかす

Tags: translation

> 幼稚園のころは適当にうまく話して納得させていたのだが、これくらいの年になると、適当に話してごまかすわけにも行かない。

This is from New Approach Japanese Intermediate Course.

Translation so far:

> During kindergarten he spoke suitably well...

So big problem is 納得させて. I just don't get what it means for this sentence.

これくらいの年になると... when it becomes this year?

And what does ごまかす have to with anything in this sentence?

Comment: I think you should make clear the part you can't figure out.

Comment: I voted your question down, but I'll be more than happy to revoke it if you show more effort. You see, if you wish to get any answer from the community, you need to first understand how this forum works by reading the rules. Additionally, I suggest reading a few old, popular topics to get a sense of how this place works. Your post would be considered "low effort" unanimously. Try to explain how you understand the sentence yourself--and why you see it that way--in a clear and well formatted structure. Then, raise your question stating where you have trouble. Good luck.

Comment: I am sorry! It wasn't my intention to just get a translation, but I really have some problems with this sentence and I didn't know how to approach them!

Comment: @kralle777 Your translation attempt seems to indicate you have misunderstood the omitted subject/object of the verbs in this sentence. Can you add the preceding sentence? 納得させる is a simple causative expression here.

Answer (score 4):

> 「幼稚園{ようちえん}のころは適当{てきとう}にうまく話{はな}して納得{なっとく}させていたのだが、これくらいの年{とし}になると、適当に話してごまかすわけにも行{い}かない。」

I will be honest.  If you really understand any important part of this sentence, it does not show in your question.

This sentence is all about the difficulty of child raising caused by the sheer fact that children grow up and get smarter rather quickly.

You state:

> "During kindergarten **he spoke** suitably well..."

Who is he?  It is not the kid who spoke; It is the unmentioned subject "we/I" who have/has been speaking to this kid.  The subject of the verb 「話す」 would likely be the parents, one of whom is the speaker.

「納得させていた」 is causative and it means "I/we used to make (the kid) understand".

「適当に」, which is used twice in the sentence, does ***not*** mean "***properly***".  Here, it is used for its colloquial meaning of "***by cutting corners***", "***rather irresponsibly***", etc.  IMHO, it is a key word for the comprehension of this sentence.

So, 「適当にうまく話して納得させていた」 would mean "***we cut corners to speak (to the kid)  and still managed to make him understand (things)***".  Why was that possible?  Because the kid was only a kindergartener back then.

Moving onto the second half... (What am I doing at 3:00 a.m.?  No wonder why I'm still single...)

So, we now know that it was a piece of cake persuading the kid just about anything in his/her kindergarten days.  What about now?

「年」 in 「これくらいの年になると」 means "***age***" and not "***year***" as you said.  So, the phrase means "***when the kid gets as old as s/he is now***".

「ごまかす」 here means "***to cheat***" or "***to lie about something***".

「ごまかすわけにも行かない」 means "there is no way you could lie about things (to persuade the kid".  I hope you are starting to get the whole picture here.

It used to be easy to ごまかす the kid because s/he was so little, but now when he is a few years older and much smarter, it is very difficult to ごまかす him/her.  **Note that there is no criminal connotation whatsoever to this usage of 「ごまかす」**.

My TL:

> "When s/he was in kindergarten, we cut corners to speak to him/her and still managed to make him/her understand (things), but when s/he has grown to be his/her (current) age, there is just no way you could lie about things (to persuade the kid)."

Answer (score 1):

納得させる is causative form of 納得する and means "convince", "persuade". This author had persuaded someone when someone was in kindergarten.

This 年 is "age", not "year" , so これくらいの年 means "such an age". これくらいの年になると means "When someone becomes such an age".

ごまかす means "deceive", "cheat". The author can't deceive someone any more, when someone becomes such an age.

So my attempt is "When he(she) was in kindergarten, I used to persuade him(her) with easy conversation, but when he(her) becomes such an age, I can't deceive him(he) any more with that."